# Booting Linux from USB on a Mac

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, refit

I'm only posting this question because it seems I've been trying to get this to work for the last 2 weeks and feel like im exhausting my options.

I'm trying to build a persistent Linux system (BlackBox) on a USB flash drive. After multiple unsuccessful attempts with casper files and different partition schemas, I continue to get a 'No Bootable Device' message after selecting the flash drive from refind.

In my latest attempt, I ran the boot-repair tool to install Grub in the EFI partition. Here is the result file http://paste.ubuntu.com/8300147/

My partition table looks like this

- sdb1 - EFI partition with Grub installed
- sdb2 - BlackBox Linux
- sdb3 - Data partition /home
- sdb4 - Swap

Can anyone see what might be the problem from the boot-repair logs? If I can provide any more useful information please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar challenge - wanting to run Ubuntu from external USB storage and came here looking for answers. Eventually I figured it out, however: Here is a solution that worked for me.

[How to boot Ubuntu on a mac from external USB storage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525845/how-to-finally-get-ubuntu-to-boot-on-a-mac-from-external-usb-storage/525906#525906)