# Modified Mac bootloader after installing Ubuntu on external HDD

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, mac

I wanted to install Ubuntu in an external HDD to boot it from my Macbook Pro.
After following Coljac's response at: 
[How to boot Ubuntu on a mac from external USB storage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525845/how-to-boot-ubuntu-on-a-mac-from-external-usb-storage?newreg=1815da3cd625400fb02fb28ba60ff9e8)

I've found that my computer no longer boots by default on MacOS X, but instead shows a GRUB prompt. I can still access the original boot menu if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> after powering the computer on, but I would like the boot to behave as it used to.

How may I get back to that configuration without breaking my Ubuntu boot on the external HDD?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve the problem?

Comment: I actually did. You may find the answer attached to the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found how to fix this and recover the original MacOS X boot menu and default boot to MacOS X.

It was originally posted as an anser by SamC in the same question I referenced before. A summary as follows:

1. Run diskutil to find the volume identifier for your EFI partition: `diskutil list`. Expect an identifier like **/dev/disk0s1**.
2. Create a mount point for the EFI partition, for example: `sudo mkdir /Volumes/EFI`
3. Mount the EFI partition in the created mount point: `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/EFI`
4. Delete the **Ubuntu** and **refind** folders and their contents: `sudo rm -r /Volumes/EFI/Ubuntu /Volumes/EFI/refind`

Restarting should show everything back to normal.